# UIImageView Following Another UIImageView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

If there is an answer which covers my question, please give me a link to it. Otherwise here is my question:

I am currently running Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7) Sprite Kit Game and would like to know wether it would be possible for a `UIImageView` to follow another `UIImageView`.

So when someone swipes in any direction, the first `UIImageView` will go that direction, and another will follow it like a snake and they all follow the one in front of them.

Edit: I would like to work like a snake. So I have many UIImageViews which represent body parts of the snake (basically small black dots) and whichever direction the head goes in which is controlled by UISwipeGestureRecogniser the others parts follow.

Comment: Would the images take up the whole screen or would they be elements on top of another view? And would they be able to be swiped in any direction or just horizontally/vertically?

Comment: I would like to work like a snake. So I have many UIImageViews which represent body parts of the snake (basically small black dots) and whichever direction the head goes in which is controlled by UISwipeGestureRecogniser the others parts follow.

Would the images take up the whole screen or would they be elements on top of another view? **They would be small elements.** Would they be able to be swiped in any direction or just horizontally/vertically? **I will look into having it in almost every direction, so 360 directions for the degrees.**

Comment: Using SpriteKit is much more suitable than using UIKit for what you are trying to do. I would say you're better off learning more about creating and maneuvering sprites than moving UIImages. Not only would it be easier but I'm sure you'd probably get much better performance as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to use `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled` property enabled. At [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift) you can find small tutorial.

Much better way is to use `UIPageViewController`, [example](http://www.makemegeek.com/uipageviewcontroller-example-ios/)